# Hosting an OWL ontology on the web to work with Apache Stanbol

Tags: ontology, owl, apache-stanbol

I am new to ontology development and I just finished my first ontology. Now I need to use this ontology within Apache Stanbol to perform re-factoring of some RDF graphs.

This is how you write a typical rule in Stanbol:

`myRule[ has(<http//myont.org/hasFather>, ?x, ?y) . has(<http/myont.org/hasBrother>, ?y, ?z) -> has(<http//myont.org/hasUncle>, ?x, ?z) ]`

I am guessing I will have to host my ontology some where online for the rules to work. Right now the base URI points to http://www.example.org/ontologies/EDXL.owl#, which is a fictional address.

I understand that the URI need not point to physical address, but would it then work with Stanbol? If this is the case, how do I host the .owl file. Would any web server do (i.e. public WWW) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, URIs do not necessarily need to point to actual resolvable pages (yet it's better if they do). So the rule engine should understand the OWL file even if it is not available online.

If you want to expose the OWL file anyway, any web server should be able to do it, just put the file somewhere accessible (`public` should work out of the box). When you use your browser to access it you should be able to see the ontology directly displayed (thanks to the special MIME type `text/turtle`).

Example: If you go to the [URI](http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing) of the OWL concept `Thing` you should see the whole ontology in your browser.